# Convert AS3 to PHP Encryption

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I would like to know if someone could convert this little code from as3 to php.

```
function hashActiveLoginKey($password)
{
    var _loc_2:* = new MD5();
    var _loc_3:* = new ByteArray();
    _loc_3.writeUTFBytes("(LHny:TyGynR" + param1);
    var _loc_4:* = _loc_2.hash(_loc_3);
    var _loc_5:* = Hex.fromArray(_loc_4);

    return Hex.fromArray(_loc_4);
} // end function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP it would be:

```
return md5("(LHny:TyGynR" . $param1);
```